# What are the "Programmer shortcuts" in emacs?

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to know what are all the programmer-useful shortcuts that exists in emacs.
I come from a netbeans background and I am trying to make myself comfortable with emacs -text only environment. So I am looking at shortcuts for "refactoring" the code, "auto-completion", "go to definition" etc.

How can all these be achieved in emacs ? What are other *programmer-useful* shortcuts ?

I'll be using emacs basically for LAMP, javascript, C, C++.

ps - you can safely assume that I know how to open a file, save a file, navigate and whatever is in the tutorial in emacs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For auto-completion, use etags with <kbd>M-x</kbd>`tags-search` or <kbd>M-x</kbd>`etags-select-find-tag`.  I use macros often to do repetitive tasks.  <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>(</kbd>`<string of useful tasks>`<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>)</kbd>.  Also, <kbd>M-x</kbd>`align-regexp` to beautify the code and make it more readable.

You should find most of the most used features by Emacs users in [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60367/the-single-most-useful-emacs-feature) here at Stackoverflow.

Comment: wow :) the link is useful, somehow I missed it when I searched for shortcuts...   
And +1 for button format styling the answer :)  I didn't know about those <kbd>blah</kbd> tags :D

Comment: The link now displays a page indicating that the question has been removed "for reasons of moderation".

Answer (score 3):

Check this [site](http://web.archive.org/web/20101113114527/http://deep.syminet.com/emacside.html)

Some the important keybindings that are not there in the tutorial are:

Previous matching bracket: C-M-b (if it doesn't work, try ESC followed by C-b)

Next matching bracket: C-M-f (or ESC C-f)

Go to start of block: C-M-u

Go to end of block: C-M-d

Start of function: C-M-a

End of function: C-M-e

Outline mode: C-u 1 C-x $ (C-x $ to revert)

Newspaper mode: C-x 3 M-x follow-mode (especially useful with today's wide-screen monitors!)

Vertical Copy

Sometimes you will need to copy a vertical patch of data, e.g. one column in a table. First press C- where you want to start copying. Then go to the end of the column and press C-x r k. To paste the column press C-x r y. (If you don't want to delete original column, just press C-_ there once to restore it and then press C-x r y at target.)

Answer (score 2):

To start, here is one :

- `Meta - /` -> does code completion

Answer (score 1):

**M-x diff-buffer-with-file**

**M-x revert-buffer**

When working with versioning (I use git), **M-x diff-buffer-with-file** is really useful. When you have a file open in a buffer in emacs, then you do a git checkout or some other action that touches that file, emacs will complain at you when you try to edit the buffer. **M-x diff-buffer-with-file** is helpful to see if you will break anything by keeping what's in the buffer. If something has changed and you want to grab the file from disc and put it in the buffer, do **M-x revert-buffer**.